# Unexpected result of train_function in TensorFlow

Tags: keras, logging, neural-network, model, conv-neural-network

I'm encountering a **ValueError** with the message **"Unexpected result of train_function (Empty logs)"** in my TensorFlow code, specifically during the training process. The error suggests using Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True) or tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) for more information on what went wrong. I'm seeking an understanding of the root cause of this error and how to find a solution.

Here are the details of my setup:

TensorFlow version: [insert your TensorFlow version]

Code snippet causing the error:

[model compilation code]
history = model.fit(train_gen, batch_size=32, epochs=100)

> [model compilation code]
> history = model.fit(train_gen, batch_size=32, epochs=100)

I have already tried adding run_eagerly=True to the model.compile() function call as suggested, but the error still persists.

I am seeking insights into the following:

1. What does the "Unexpected result of train_function (Empty logs)" error indicate?
2. How can I get more detailed information or logs about the error to help identify the issue?
3. Are there any common pitfalls or reasons why this error occurs during the training process?

Also, I use:

```
def generate_image_and_label(image_paths, labels):
    for image_path, label in zip(image_paths, labels):
        print(label)
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(416, 416))
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
        yield image, label

def get_images_with_labels(labels, directory):
    image_paths = []  # List of image file paths
    # Logic to populate image_paths and labels based on directory and labels input
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generate_image_and_label,
        args=(image_paths, labels),
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(416, 416, 3), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(232), dtype=tf.int32)
        )
    )
    return dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

for labeling, and after a neural network followed by:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = False),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and

```
history = model.fit(train_gen,epochs=100)




test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_gen, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Comment: Did you mean to edit this? `TensorFlow version: [insert your TensorFlow version]` It looks like you are expected to provide a TF version here.